# PHP: Google Analytics 4 account provisioning - "account token is missing"

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm working with the account provisioning functions in the Google Analytics 4 Admin API. I set up and make the api call, and get the provisioning ticket ID back. I use this code to create the provisioning ticket:

```
    $env_string = "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=PATH_TO_MY_JSON_FILE";
    putenv($env_string);

    $analytics_service_client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient();

    try
    {
        $new_account_name = create_my_next_account_name();
        
        $new_account = new Account( ['display_name' => $new_account_name,
                                     'region_code'  => 'US',
                                    ] );
        $redirectUri = $this->getAccountFinalizeCallbackUri();

        $response = $analytics_service_client->provisionAccountTicket( [ 'account' => $new_account, 'redirectUri' => $redirectUri  ] );
        if ( $response instanceof ProvisionAccountTicketResponse )
        {
            $tosBase = "https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?provisioningSignup=false#/termsofservice/";

            $provisionURL = $tosBase . "/{$response->getAccountTicketId()}"; // oops, extra slash
            print "GOTO: $provisionURL\n";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("what did we get back? " . get_class($response) );
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        Log::error( "Error provisioning account ticket: " . $ex->getMessage() );
    }
    finally
    {
        $analytics_service_client->close();
    }
```

I use that ticket in the ToS URL:

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?provisioningSignup=false#/termsofservice//TICKET_ID
```

My code put the extra slash in there before the ticket id, but that usually doesn't matter, so I opened up that URL in my browser (incognito window), and got the error message:

```
Error: Account token is missing.
```

Ok, so maybe that extra slash DOES matter! Let's try:

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?provisioningSignup=false#/termsofservice/TICKET_ID
```

This time I get the error message:

```
Error: Access denied.
```

Obviously neither is the desired option. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I am using the alpha code for the AnalyticsAdminService client.

Comment: Are the Users the same?  The user who made the ProvisionAccountTicket request and the user who visited the analytics link? I believe the token is bound to a specific user.

Comment: Hmm... the provision request was made by a service account. I'll check that out, thanks